# HTML Frameset issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, frames, frameset

I have a main page (test3.html) which has a `<frameset>` with 2 frames;

Now the top frame is an HTML file always..
But the bottom frame can be a PDF (desktop ver) OR HTML (iPad ver) depending on the condition

I know how to detect iPad or Desktop..So my question is not on how to do that..

For the bottom frame, The HTML (iPad) is just going to have 1 link (but that is dynamic). Is it necessary to call that in a frame? i.e. create a separate bottom_frame.html

I mean is there some way by which it can be coded in the same main page (test3.html) and attached to that page? The reason I am not looking for separate page for bottom frame (iPad HTML) is because it will only have 1 link and that would have to dynamically parsed (and I am getting that info in the main page already..so don't want to create a separate page for that again..)

Below is the URL of the main page;
http://ipad.atwebpages.com/test3.html

Comment: Do you mean attaching a pdf to an html page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I approve of the use of framesets, but you could use a [data uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) for the lower frame. Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<frameset rows="121,*" cols="*">
  <frame src="head.html" name="topFrame">
  <frame src="data:text/html;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+DQo8dGl0bGU+VGVzdCBDYXNlPC90aXRsZT4NCjxkaXY+TG93ZXIgRnJhbWU8L2Rpdj4=" name="bottomFrame">
</frameset>
</html>
```